# how to use append method in table

Tags: jquery, html

append method i am using first time , its not working in my table tag i am using span tag, using span tag i am appending to code in left to right but its not working properly as like i manually put code its working proper but using append method its not working proper i don't know resign why its happening with code.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td height="21" align="left" valign="bottom"><font face="Agency-Roman" color="#000000"><br></font></td>
        <td align="left" valign="bottom"><font face="Agency-Roman" color="#000000"><br></font></td>
        <td align="left" valign="bottom"><font face="Agency-Roman" color="#000000"><br></font></td>
        <td align="left" valign="bottom"><font face="Agency-Roman" color="#000000"><br></font></td>
        <td align="left" valign="bottom"><font face="Agency-Roman" color="#000000"><br></font></td>
        <td align="left" valign="bottom"><font face="Agency-Roman" color="#000000"><br></font></td>
        <td align="left" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><font face="Agency-Roman" color="#000000"><br></font></td>
        <td colspan="14" align="center" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#FFFF00"><font face="Agency-Roman" color="#000000">Week 1</font></td>

        <!-- <td align="left" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><font face="Agency-Roman" color="#000000"><br></font></td>
        <td colspan="14" align="center" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#FF6600"><font face="Agency-Roman" color="#FFFFFF">Week 2</font></td>
        --><!-- this code is comment when manually put this code is working proper -->
        <span1 class="divq"></span1>

    </tr>
</table>
```

my jquery code is

```
$(document).on('click', '.hello2', function (e) {
    $("span1").append(`
        <td align="left" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
            <font face="Agency-Roman" color="#000000"><br></font>
        </td>
        <td colspan="14" align="center" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#FF6600">
            <font face="Agency-Roman" color="#FFFFFF">Week 2</font>
        </td>
    `);
});
```

i also want to know how to utilize append method , can i use with class also & there is method like append via i can append left to right and top to bottom run append method

Comment: remove `e.preventDefault();` and check.

Comment: I don't think there is `span1` html tag? have you tried using just `<span>`?

Comment: Works fine. Whats issue ..   See here http://jsfiddle.net/cx09v7yj/

Comment: i have remove e.preventDefault(); and span1 tag from my question sir thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var i =2;
$(document).ready( function () {

$('#clickMe').click(function(){
        $("#specialTr").append(            
       '<td align="left" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><font face="Agency-Roman" color="#000000"><br></font></td>\n\
<td colspan="14" align="center" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#FF6600"><font face="Agency-Roman" color="#FFFFFF">Week '+i+'</font></td>'

                );
          i++;
                
           })
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
     <tr id="specialTr">
            <td height="21" align="left" valign="bottom"><font face="Agency-Roman" color="#000000"><br></font></td>
            <td align="left" valign="bottom"><font face="Agency-Roman" color="#000000"><br></font></td>
            <td align="left" valign="bottom"><font face="Agency-Roman" color="#000000"><br></font></td>
            <td align="left" valign="bottom"><font face="Agency-Roman" color="#000000"><br></font></td>
            <td align="left" valign="bottom"><font face="Agency-Roman" color="#000000"><br></font></td>
            <td align="left" valign="bottom"><font face="Agency-Roman" color="#000000"><br></font></td>
            <td align="left" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><font face="Agency-Roman" color="#000000"><br></font></td>
            <td colspan="14" align="center" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#FFFF00"><font face="Agency-Roman" color="#000000">Week 1</font></td>

    <!--                <td align="left" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><font face="Agency-Roman" color="#000000"><br></font></td>
                    <td colspan="14" align="center" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#FF6600"><font face="Agency-Roman" color="#FFFFFF">Week 2</font></td>
        --><!-- this code is comment when manually put this code its working proper -->

      </tr>
</table>

<button id="clickMe" >Click Me</button>
```

What is the `span1` tag? Jquery only supporting for HTML elements.
 You can appen the tr directly to td

Comment: sir, ur code is working properly i have more then <tr> tag in my project on one page now i want to put only at this tr tag how its possible in my code or any class using in my code for this tr tag any other way

Comment: @Developer Updated the answer. You can give a id to tr

Comment: thankyou sir giving me a valuable time to my question its working proper code in my project thankyou once again

Comment: sir, how can i increase week 1,week 2,week 3...week n goes on  also with this question code

Comment: @Developer Updated the answer.

Comment: sir, how to increase rowspan  <td colspan="2" rowspan="1" from jquery can u give a example